# HTML5 MIME type for f4v

Tags: html, mime-types

What is the mime type to accept file .f4v type in HTML 5?

I have tried "video/f4v" and "video/mp4" but they do not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using "video/x-f4v" solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks dude!  This was super helpful in my Sitecore 7.0 Instance.  I tried tons of things before I found this.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`.f4v` is a Flash video file so it won't work with HTML5, only within a Flash video player. I suggest that you use something like [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) to convert it to both MP4 and WebM and then you can use HTML5 video.